# Firebase Social Logins not working, it says the domain is not authorized but it is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to get to why this is happening but I can't find where the problem is.

Whenever I try to use social logins in my React-Firebase app, a popup opens but then closes instantly (Firefox) or loads infinitely (Chrome, Edge...).

Either way, I get this message from the console:

`The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working. Add your domain (localhost) to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.`

You will think that I haven't done what it says, but I have:

[image: Firebase]

I've also set localhost at BrowserKey and WebClient (there is 2 of this, I assume one for Facebook and one for Google login) at `console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials`

Any ideas why this is still happening?

Comment: For a specific problem like this, probably better to reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).